# How to pas querystring to another page using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to redirect from current i.e home page to another page with querystring using window.location.href but it redirects to current i.e. home
page again.
I dont know whats missing though code looks fine.

current URL: http://win-aslbkn4mm3v:10001/sitepages/Content%20Page/rch_home.aspx

Expecting URL: http://win-aslbkn4mm3v:10001/sitepages/Content%20Page/Doctors.aspx?qn=ddd&qs=ddd&qd=ddd

but Getting URL: //win-aslbkn4mm3v:10001/sitepages/Content%20Page/rch_home.aspx

```
function SearchDoctor()
        {
            debugger;
            var Name = document.getElementById("SearchName").value;
            var Speciality = document.getElementById("SearchSpeciality");
            var spl = Speciality.options[Speciality.selectedIndex].text;
            var Department = document.getElementById("SearchDepartment");
            var dept = Department.options[Department.selectedIndex].text;
            var mainUrl= '../../../Doctors.aspx?qn=' + Name + '&qs=' + Speciality + '&qd=' + Department;
            window.location=mainurl; 
        }
```

Comment: That code won't redirect anything at all (although the question does lead me to wonder why you aren't just submitting a form)

Comment: m using window.location or window.location.href you can see updated code still it doesnt work.
I already have master page having form tag I dont think it would be a good idea to use another form tag on content page?

Comment: "I already have master page having form tag I dont think it would be a good idea to use another form tag on content page?" — Oh no. Is that at awful ASP.NET webforms thing which wraps every page in a massive form? I thought people didn't use that any more :(

Comment: It *sounds* like you might be submitting your form, which is overriding the `window.location` assignment, but your test case isn't complete enough to tell. http://sscce.org/

Comment: I would suggest you take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx).  This would explain how to get values from one place to another in asp.net.

Comment: Thanks all. @Quentin your comment leads me to solve the problem.
As I was using the button inside form tag, it was trying to submit the same form again.
Thanks again.